# How to integrate a custom Screen Capture App inside my HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, api, iframe

I am trying to integrate a screenshot tool or a Snipping tool kind of application inside a HTML page that I developed.

Basically the app should allow me to snipe a part of my current webpage and save it in picture format. Or it can even capture the entire page also. Anything works.

For the record, the content of my webpage contains an iframe whose source is - https://www.mathxl.com/info/exercise.aspx?fromask=yes&dataid=f919d33b-99fd-4fb5-90a8-a8a4c9894795

The Screen Capture Application should capture the dynamic contents that I insert inside the loaded iframe flash content as well.

Any kind of suggestions or information about a 3rd Party API (even paid version works) would be helpful.

*PS - I tried HTML2Canvas.js, it didn't work.*